# Datatable in JSF is not going through each var in list but return list

Tags: java, jsf, datatable

I'm making an application with a few jsf pages.

```
    <h:dataTable value="#{S1bean.getTweetsByUserId(1)}" var="tweet">
        <h:column>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{tweet.getTweet()}"/>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{tweet.getDatum().toString()}"/>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{tweet.getVanaf()}"/>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
```

Instead of giving tweet a Tweet-object, it gives a collection of tweets.
So it will not recognize the getTweet()-method which returns a string.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try using the `<c:forEach>` where `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core` is the namespace for `c`.

Comment: What is the method signature of `getTweetsByUserId(1)`?

Comment: @R.J I get a 'java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space'.

Comment: @McDowell the 1 is an int and it returns a Collection<User>

Comment: I would recommend to use the members directly, not through the getters. Let the engine handle that: #{tweet.tweet}, etc.. Also to print the datum in the appropriate format, use a converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use an Object[] instead of a Collection in my bean.

Answer (score 2):

Until the upcoming JSF 2.2, the `<h:dataTable>` doesn't support a `Collection`. Right now, it only supports `List`, `Map` and `Object[]`.